# Refactor C# code using DRY principle

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable, dry

I can't seem to figure out how to refactor a particular section in my code. I have reduced it from two separate methods into a single method with an additional variable (`TopOrBottomPercent`) being passed as a flag to determine the appropriate `OrderBy` and `Where` clause (since those were the only differences between the two methods). Now I am left with two identical ways of loading a `DataTable` (once filtered).

Relevant code below:

```
    private object LoadPercentDiffPoP(String TopOrBottomPercent, DateTime prevPeriodStart, DateTime prevPeriodEnd, DateTime currPeriodStart, DateTime currPeriodEnd) {

        ...

        // Populating data from dictionary to grid
        if (TopOrBottomPercent.ToLower() == "top") {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ReportData> keyValuePair in ReportDataElements.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.CommPercentDiff > 0)
                .OrderByDescending(P => P.Value.CommPercentDiff).Take(itemsToReturn)) {
                detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[]{
                    keyValuePair.Value.LocationVar,
                    keyValuePair.Value.PropertyID,
                    keyValuePair.Value.Property,
                    keyValuePair.Value.IndividualID,
                    keyValuePair.Value.Individual,
                    keyValuePair.Value.PrevPeriodComm,
                    keyValuePair.Value.CurrPeriodComm,
                    keyValuePair.Value.CommPercentDiff
                });
            }
        } else if (TopOrBottomPercent.ToLower() == "lower") {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ReportData> keyValuePair in ReportDataElements.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.CommPercentDiff < 0 
                && kvp.Value.CommPercentDiff >= Convert.ToDecimal(maxPercentDisplayed)).OrderBy(P => P.Value.CommPercentDiff).Take(itemsToReturn)) {
                detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[]{
                    keyValuePair.Value.LocationVar,
                    keyValuePair.Value.PropertyID,
                    keyValuePair.Value.Property,
                    keyValuePair.Value.IndividualID,
                    keyValuePair.Value.Individual,
                    keyValuePair.Value.PrevPeriodComm,
                    keyValuePair.Value.CurrPeriodComm,
                    keyValuePair.Value.CommPercentDiff
                });
            }
        }

        return detailTable;

    }
```

Any assistance is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the expression step by step instead of as a single statement:

```
private object LoadPercentDiffPoP(String TopOrBottomPercent, DateTime prevPeriodStart, DateTime prevPeriodEnd, DateTime currPeriodStart, DateTime currPeriodEnd) {

  ...

  // Populating data from dictionary to grid

  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ReportData>> query = ReportDataElements;

  if (TopOrBottomPercent.ToLower() == "top") {
    query = query
      .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.CommPercentDiff > 0)
      .OrderByDescending(P => P.Value.CommPercentDiff);
  } else {
    query = query
      .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.CommPercentDiff < 0 && kvp.Value.CommPercentDiff >= Convert.ToDecimal(maxPercentDisplayed))
      .OrderBy(P => P.Value.CommPercentDiff);
  }

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ReportData> keyValuePair in query.Take(itemsToReturn)) {
    detailTable.Rows.Add(new object[]{
      keyValuePair.Value.LocationVar,
      keyValuePair.Value.PropertyID,
      keyValuePair.Value.Property,
      keyValuePair.Value.IndividualID,
      keyValuePair.Value.Individual,
      keyValuePair.Value.PrevPeriodComm,
      keyValuePair.Value.CurrPeriodComm,
      keyValuePair.Value.CommPercentDiff
    });
  }
  return detailTable;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, not only did you save me from redundancy, but also a few lines of code. Thank you for the knowledge gained!

Comment: It is really very good suggestion, I would like to add some constant, instead of "top", if tomorrow something change it will be easy to update.

Comment: @SalmanFarsi: Good point. I would even go so far as saying that interpreting the string should be in the user interface part of the application, and this method should accept a boolean or enum value to indicate which part to get.

Comment: I agree @SalmanFarsi I used "top" just as a quick way to differentiate between what called it. I have two grids (among others), Top % and Bottom %, each grid makes a call to this method to return the datasource.

Comment: @Guffa: I like the idea of using enum value instead, I will switch to that.